# preventing to add the same object in a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student s = new Student(NameBox.Text,LastNameBox.Text,Int32.Parse(IdBox.Text));
        List<Student> j = new List<Student>();

        if (!j.Contains(s))
        {
            j.Add(s);
            ListBox1.Items.Add(s.getName() +' ' +s.getLastName() +' '+s.getId());
        }

    }
```

So I'm going to write the info in the textboxes and will click the button. student S will get created with those info, but if I click the button again. The same object will be on the listbox.

Comment: Whats wrong with the above code?

Comment: So you create a new empty list, and check to see if it contains some random object. Surprisingly, it never does. Anyway, you need to keep a private `List<Student> _students` which contains all the students in the listbox. Check `_students.Any(st => st.getId() == newId)` before adding a new student to the listbox. IF and ONLY if you add the new student to the listbox, add it to `_students` at the same time.

Comment: And use properties in your classes, not this `getId()` stuff.

Comment: Inside your `if` statement, create a new `ListItem` with the text/value you need instead of doing it within the `add`. You can then do `if (ListBox1.Items.Contains(myItem))...`